# Probability of detector working

Tags: probability

The number of elements that fall into detector is Poisson probability with expectation equal to 1 element per day.If less than 3 elements fall into the detector , the detector works.If 3 elements fall into the detector the probability of the detector to works is $\frac{1}{2}$.If more than 3 elements fall into the detector, it stops working.

1)What is the probability the detector to stop working?

2)If a unit contains 1000 detectors,what is the probability at least 200 to stop working?

My attempt : We have $Po(1)$ In order the detector to work the probability is

:$$\sum_{n=1}^{2}  \frac{1^ke^{-1}}{k!}  + \frac{1^3e^{-1}}{3!}*\frac{1}{2} = A$$
So in order not to work the probability will be $1-A$

for 2) the answer should be $$\sum_{n=200}^{1000} (1-A)^n*A^{1000-n} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1) it should be $$\sum_{n=0}^{2}  \frac{1^ke^{-1}}{k!}  + \frac{1^3e^{-1}}{3!}*\frac{1}{2} = A$$
for (2) the given answer is worng. The probability that $n$ detectors stop working is $$\binom{1000}{n}(1-A)^nA^{1000-n}$$ and the desired probability is
$$\sum_{n=200}^{1000}\binom{1000}{n}(1-A)^nA^{1000-n}$$